# Check for Special Characters in C

Tags: c, char, special-characters, equality

I got some help on how to see if a "string" in C contains a specific character. In short:

```
if(*s=='x') { //Where x is some character
    //Do something
}
```

Now, as far as I can see, this works for letters in the English alphabet (a-z, A-Z).

However, how can I check if the current character equals a special character (such as **æ**, **ø**, or **å**)?

Comment: Do you know what encoding you are using for your strings? This will work for single-byte encodings (e.g., Latin1, Windows-1252 or MacRoman) and (providing `*s` is of the correct type) for `wchar` or `tchar` Unicde strings, but not for variable-length multibyte encodings such as UTF8.

Answer (score 2):

Just compare to the ASCII code of the character:

```
if(*s==10) { //Where 10 is the ASCII code of the special character
    //Do something
}
```

You can find your ASCII code here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I don't think "ASCII" is what the OP is looking for, as he is already covering that.

Comment: Character such as `æ, ø, å` are not ASCII codes.  [American Standard Code for Information Interchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: Sure they are æ =145  , ø = 237 , å = 134
They are Extended ASCII Codes

Comment: The most meaning we can eke out of "Extended ASCII" is 1) not ASCII and 2) one byte encoding, therefore <= 256 characters. That narrows it down to several dozen character sets. At least when you say "ASCII" we know exactly what it means (it's probably wrong, though).

Comment: and, of course, 3) a superset of ASCII with identical encodings for the common characters. Still doesn't narrow it down much.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you should be using a function for this: `strchr` for looking for a single byte, or `strstr` for looking for more than a single byte.

Also, in general C does not know about characters, it only knows about bytes.  A special character may be a single byte - æ in iso8859-1 encoding is `\xe6`, for example - or it may be more than one byte: the same character in utf-8 encoding is the 2-byte sequence `\xc3\xa6`.

To search a utf-8 encoded string for æ you could use

```
strstr(s, "\xc3\xa6")
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare the character to the actual value (as long as the value is between 0 and 255).

See the æ [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86#Computer_encodings_and_entering) page for particular values.  So

> if (*s == 0xe6)

for lower case

> if (*s == 0xc6)

for upper case